# How can I combine date with WHERE clause

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a WHERE condition and i want filter two reports in first I want to onlu have items from 2020 year and in the other from 2019 I m trying to write it like this:

```
[UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia]>#01.01.2019#<#01.01.2020#
```

AND In 2020

```
[UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia]>#01.01.2020#<#01.01.2021#
```

But it doesnt work, my table is UMOWY and and the column name is data_wygasniecia the date is stored in date format. Can you please help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9reb5.jpg
[image: photo where how where i try]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct syntax for date expressions:

```
[UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia] Between #2019/01/01# And #2019/12/31#
```

or, if a time component is present:

```
[UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia] >= #2019/01/01# 
And
[UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia] < #2020/01/01#
```

or, if the recordset isn't too large:

```
Year([UMOWY]![data_wygasniecia]) = 2019
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it shows an error, i tried all of your ideas :( and here is photo https://imgur.com/a/IYZ3Bf0

Comment: Then your field is not of data type DateTime.